# C# - Example for Handshaking with SerialPort class

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to communicate with an MBED through serial ports.

I've read the msdn site but I don't understand.

Can anyone teach me or show examples of how to use `SerialPort.Handshake` (`XonXoff` or `RequestToSend`)?

My main request how to set: If C# reads a certain string, then send data.

Comment: msdn is your friend. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You don't "use" it, you must give it a value that matches the handshaking that the device requires.  Getting it wrong causes problems, you won't get any data from the device or the device ignores what you sends or you'll suffer from random data loss.  No point in asking strangers on the Internet, talk to whomever is familiar with the device, they always know what is required.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the insight, did not know how handshaking works in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i think that Handshaking is not what you need. Handshaking is a low level communication, to control when to send data or not. [more about handshaking](https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/RS-232_flow_control.html)

> My main request how to set: If C# reads a certain string, then send
>   data.

What you need is a continuous data reading or an event, and after certain string is read - to send some data.

Let me find some examples.

```
void connect(){
    _port = new SerialPort();
    // set port parameters
    _port.DataReceived += portDataReceived; //set the data received event
    _port.Open();
}
void portDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string data = _port.ReadExisting();
    if(data.Contains("data-start")) //check for the start data
    {
         CreateReply(); // your reply
    }
}
```

You can read the data in a while loop, but take a note that an infinite loop executed in the main thread will block your program from responding.

```
void connectAndRead(){
    _port = new SerialPort();
    // set port parameters
    _port.Open();
    _stopReading = false;

    var dataBuffer = "";
    while(!_stopReading)
    {
        dataBuffer += _serialPort.ReadLine();
        if(!dataBuffer.Contains("data-start")) //check for the start data
            continue;

        CreateReply(); // your reply
        _stopReading = true; // exit loop
    }
}
```